# SQL: Need to select items by different conditions

Tags: sql

**My table looks like this -**
[image]

**Explanation**
I'm working on an online shop that sells **tours** and **spa**. I'm showing all together on one page.

**What I need to select?**
1. All spa products (based on "Spa" column), no conditions.
2. All parent tours that have children with an upcoming date.

**Meaning**
Products ID 1, 4, 5.

**Why?**
Product 6 have a child, but from 1999. And although product 1 have one child at 2000, it has another one in 2017. All spa products are selected by default, without conditions.

*I hope I made my question clear as I could. I would appreciate any help, my SQL is really bad.*

Comment: Are you using a relational database management system?

Comment: @Strawberry, I'm not sure what your'e asking, I'll answer by saying that all products are stored on the same table which is "products".

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Why would row 1 be selected--there are no children and it does not have an upcoming date.  Your criteria states "All parent tours that have children with an upcoming date."  Also, this is VERY basic SQL--you really need to go through a SQL tutorial--just having someone else write the code for you isn't going to help you learn.

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure isn't great. Really, as you have a parent -> child relationship as well as special types, it would be better to have three tables e.g. Product, ProductType and ProductItem or some such nomenclature. The parent table contains the ID, name and typeId (having a flag limits you to only two types, you may chooes to have more). Your child table contains a ID, parent ID, name and date. Then you can simply use a foreign key constraint to link the two and do some simple SQL to join it all up e.g.

```
SELECT pt.Name, pi.Name, pi.Date from ProductItem pi
INNER JOIN Product p on p.id = pi.parentID
INNER JOIN ProductType pt on p.typeId = pt.id
WHERE pi.date > now() --The "Now" part depends on your RDBMS as it's different on different systems
AND pt.name = "TOUR"
UNION
SELECT pt.Name, p.Name, 'N/A' from Product p
INNER JOIN ProductType pt on pt.id = p.typeId
WHERE pt.name = "SPA"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I work on a pre-built system and I can't change the entire logic and tables.